# Split a coma separated string in a particular format

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column which represent hierarchy path,  so when i execute the SQL query

```
select  hierachypath from mytable where id=10
```

for a particular row i will get the result like this

```
hieracheypath
--------------
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

select  hierachypath from mytable where id=10
```

I want to get a result like

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4
1,2,3
1,2
1
```

OR

```
1
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

I had try this way

```
Declare @heiracheypath nvarchar(4000) ='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'
declare    @Result TABLE (Column1   VARCHAR(100))
Declare @tcount int
 SELECT @tcount=(len(@heiracheypath) - LEN(REPLACE(@heiracheypath,',','')) + 1) 

DECLARE @IntLocation INT
        WHILE (CHARINDEX(',',    @heiracheypath, 0) > 0)
        BEGIN
              SET @IntLocation =   CHARINDEX(',',    @heiracheypath, 0)      
              INSERT INTO   @Result (Column1)
              --LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank spaces are   removed
              SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@heiracheypath,   0, @IntLocation)))   
              SET @heiracheypath = STUFF(@heiracheypath,   1, @IntLocation,   '') 
        END
        INSERT INTO   @Result (Column1)
        SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(@heiracheypath))--LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank spaces are removed
select * from @Result
```

but the result was

```
Column1
-------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: And what have you tried to get the result?

Comment: i tried with cte

Comment: but the case is i need to avoid the cte tables

Comment: Can you process the data in your code instead?

Comment: in the actual scenario i need to get all parents with out using cte

Comment: is the result meant to be 10 rows? or 1 row with breaklines?

Comment: yes it depends on how many coma separated values are there

Comment: I need to add the result in to a temp table

Comment: How come "_the case is i need to avoid the cte tables_"?

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question Looks like T-SQL - so here's a simple solution without common table expressions:

```
DECLARE @heiracheypath nvarchar(4000) ='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10';


SELECT SUBSTRING(@heiracheypath, 1, ci-1) As Paths
FROM 
(
    SELECT CHARINDEX(',',@heiracheypath, N) As ci 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP(LEN(@heiracheypath)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) As N
        FROM sys.objects A
    ) AS Tally

    UNION 
        SELECT LEN(@heiracheypath) + 1

) As CommaIndexes
WHERE ci > 0
ORDER BY ci
```

The `Tally` derived table contains numbers from 1 to the length of the value,
the `CommaIndexes` table contains the distinct indexes of each comma in the value,
the `union` part is to also return the full string,
and the outer most select statement simply use `substring` to return the relevant parts of the string.

This could be simplified further by combining the tally derived table with the commaIndexs derived table:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@heiracheypath, 1, ci-1) As Paths
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@heiracheypath)) CHARINDEX(',',@heiracheypath, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID)) As ci 
    FROM sys.objects A
    UNION  SELECT LEN(@heiracheypath) + 1
) As CommaIndexes
WHERE ci > 0
ORDER BY ci
```

Result:

```
Paths
1
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: This is almost what i want

Comment: The results are exactly the same as your expected results - What's the difference?